# remove module in requirejs to fire it again

Tags: jquery, html, requirejs

so I'm using [Require.js](http://requirejs.org) to dynamically load `js` files which works pretty neat so far. But how do I unload a module that one can fire it again.

A plain example:

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
  $('#trigger').click(function() { 
    require(["view"], function(fn) {
        // some callback
    });
  });
});
```

I'm loading `jquery` to assign a clickhandler function to a button named `#trigger`. I do also have a `view.js` file which contains, to keep it easy lets say, an `alert("test");`

So when I'm loading the page and press `#trigger` everything works as expected. But I can't press `#trigger` again, because the `alert()` inside `view.js` has already fired. How would I unload this module to get the alert everytime I press `#trigger`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in the view so that it doesn't automatically fire. Requiring something that automatically invokes itself is quite rare. So if you changed your code to the following you could invoke the view function multiple times:

```
require(["jquery", "view"], function($, view) {
  $('#trigger').click(function() { 
      view.load();
  });
});
```

And your view file would be something like:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    var load: function () {
        // Do some stuff here
    }

    return {
        load: load
    }
});
```